# IIS URL Rewrite rule not being triggered

Tags: wcf, iis, url-rewriting

I am pretty sure that I have my WCF URL Rewrite Rule coded correctly in my Web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RemoveSVC" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="MyWebSvc/([a-zA-Z]+)-svc/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="MyWebSvc/{R:1}.svc/{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The rewrite rule seems to be working in the "Test pattern..." widget.  For instance:

```
http://localhost/MyWebSvc/thinga-svc/majigs
```

gets correctly mapped to:

```
{R-1} thinga
{R-2} majigs
```

And I would like the URL to be re-written to:

```
http://localhost/MyWebSvc/thinga.svc/majigs
```

Seems simple enough, however, when I try to test the URL from a browser:

```
http://localhost/MyWebSvc/thinga.svc/majigs
```

works, but

```
http://localhost/MyWebSvc/thinga-svc/majigs
```

does not appear to be re-written, and I get a 404 response code.  Do I have to configure the rule to be triggered with some other setting?

Comment: Your rule should work. What if, as a test, you replace `type="Rewrite"` with `type="Redirect"` to see where it gets you?

Comment: @cheesemacfly  I tried with the Redirect rather than Rewrite, but I got the same result.

Comment: That is really weird...are you sure your setup is in the right place (on the right site)? Can you try to run the [Failed Request Tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see if any error shows up?

Comment: @cheesemacfly  I had installed the FRT tool.  One weird thing is that in the configuration of the FRT tool, the "Rewrite" option in "Select Trace Providers" does not show up.  Although, the "URL Rewrite" feature does appear in IIS Manager.  I went ahead and tried the rewrite and the log has the following:

4. -PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START 

ModuleName RewriteModule  0 ms Verbose

5. -PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END 

ModuleName RewriteModule  
NotificationStatus  NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE

Comment: and also: 


and

18. -NOTIFY_MODULE_START 

ModuleName RewriteModule
Notification  BEGIN_REQUEST
fIsPostNotification false 0 ms Verbose

19. -NOTIFY_MODULE_END

ModuleName RewriteModule
Notification BEGIN_REQUEST
fIsPostNotificationEvent false
NotificationStatus NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE

Comment: Can you try with a really simple redirect rule? (for example one with `url="test"` that redirects to `google.com`) Do you see anything significantly different in the trace?

Comment: @cheesemacfly  18. -NOTIFY_MODULE_START 

ModuleName RewriteModule  
Notification  BEGIN_REQUEST  
fIsPostNotification false   0 ms Verbose
19. -NOTIFY_MODULE_END 

ModuleName RewriteModule  
Notification BEGIN_REQUEST  
fIsPostNotificationEvent false  
NotificationStatus NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE

Comment: @cheesemacfly  4. -PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START 

ModuleName RewriteModule  0 ms Verbose
5. -PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END 

ModuleName RewriteModule  
NotificationStatus NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE

Comment: @cheesemacfly  106. -NOTIFY_MODULE_START 

ModuleName RewriteModule  
Notification SEND_RESPONSE  
fIsPostNotification false  0 ms Verbose
107. -NOTIFY_MODULE_END 

ModuleName RewriteModule  
Notification SEND_RESPONSE  
fIsPostNotificationEvent false  
NotificationStatus NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE

Comment: @cheesemacfly  The URL I put in the browser was http://localhost/MyWebSvc/test and I got a 404 with the Requested URL being http://localhost/MyWebSvc/google.com with the physical path set to <full_path>\google.com .  So the redirect did happen.

Comment: Can you put the full logs files somewhere available on the internet? (pastebin or equivalent)

Comment: @cheesemacfly  The FRT log is at http://pastebin.com/DDxgXF9U

Comment: So how is this website setup? Is `MyWebSvc` a sub folder in your website or what is it? It seems like the rewrite module can not find the path so maybe it is setup a level too deep.

Comment: @cheesemacfly  MyWebSvc is an application under "Default Web Site" in IIS Manager.  The physical path to MyWebSvc is the location on my hard drive where the Visual Studio Solution is.  Resource are found properly when the URL is not re-written.

Comment: Ok, so what if you remove `MyWebSvc/` in the rule match AND action?

Comment: Sure, it can sometimes be hard to track down issues like this one :)